# error in java executable jar file connecting to database

Tags: eclipse, executable-jar

i have a error in connecting executable jar file to database,it gave me error that there is a mismatch driver and application but when same code compiled and run through eclipse it does not gave me an error
few days back there was no error suddenly it started giving me a error
[image]

Comment: can you describe the question more clearly,otherwise, nobody can help you

Comment: i have made a executable jar file with help of eclipse when i run  it it doesnt connect nd gives a driver and application mismatch dSN error but if i run it the code through eclipse it runs fine no such error persist

Comment: Please quote the actual error message.

Comment: @user2558479: please post some error trace.... Stack Overflow can solve error not by magic but by looking at proper logs and error message.